# FactoryGirl and testing has_many with association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I am trying to run a simple test that checks that an object can be built with its associations

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :portfolio_sectors
  has_many :sectors, through: :portfolio_sectors
  has_many :portfolio_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :portfolio_images, allow_destroy: true
end

class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :portfolio_sectors
  has_many :portfolios, through: :portfolio_sectors
end
```

My test looks like this

```
RSpec.describe Portfolio, type: :model do
  it 'should have a valid Factory' do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio)).to be_valid
  end
end
```

The Portfolio Factory looks like

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :portfolio do |p|
    p.title 'Test portfolio title'
    p.overview 'test sentence for the overview section of portfolio'
    p.url 'http://bbc.co.uk'
    p.after(:create) do |portfolio|
      portfolio.sectors = FactoryGirl.create(:associated_sector, portfolio: portfolio)
    end
    p.after(:create) do |portfolio|
     portfolio.portfolio_images = [FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio_image, portfolio: portfolio)]
    end
 end
end
```

So when this test runs i get

```
Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio)).to be_valid
expected #<Portfolio id: nil,
           overview: "test sentence for the overview section of portfoli...", 
           title: "Test portfolio title",
           sector_id: nil, 
           url: "http://bbc.co.uk", 
           created_at: nil, 
           updated_at: nil> 
to be valid, but got errors: Sectors Choose At Least 1 Sector
```

Which i can see why as no sector id is present.

How can i pass the sector id through when creating a portfolio?

Or am i approaching this incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You redefine `create` callback here:

```
p.after(:create) do |portfolio|
  portfolio.sectors = FactoryGirl.create(:associated_sector, portfolio: portfolio)
end
p.after(:create) do |portfolio|
  portfolio.portfolio_images = [FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio_image, portfolio: portfolio)]
end
```

There is no magic, the second one redefines the first one. Use subsequent calls:

```
p.after(:create) do |portfolio|
  portfolio.sectors = FactoryGirl.create(:associated_sector, portfolio: portfolio)
  portfolio.portfolio_images = [FactoryGirl.build(:portfolio_image, portfolio: portfolio)]
  portfolio.save!
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though it looks similar to what i have (apart from combining the after creates , so thanks for that), i still get an error `but got errors: Sectors Choose At Least 1 Sector`. When a User creates a portfolio for example they will be selecting from a list of Sectors from the database in a dropdown for example, does this make a difference ?

Comment: Try to add `portfolio.save!` in the very end of `after(:create)` callback. It sounds like the changes are not propagated. Also, `portfolio.reload` before check might help.

Comment: unfortunately that has not helped, nor the reload.. To look at this at a different angle then, how would you write this test? maybe I could learn some things from you that way and maybe change my approach, thanks